# How do I select the h2 element in the 2nd box?

Tags: html, css

I am using bootstrap grid structure. I coded a block containing 3 boxes with css. But I cannot select the 2nd and 3rd h2 elements.

```
 <!-- 1st BOX-->
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="kutu">
      <h2>1st TITLE</h2>

      <div class="items">
      </div>
      <h3>test</h3>
    </div>
    <a href="#">test</a>
</div>
<!-- 1st BOX END-->


<!-- 2st BOX-->
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="kutu">
      <h2>2nd TITLE</h2>

      <div class="items">
      </div>
      <h3>test</h3>
    </div>
    <a href="#">test</a>
</div>
<!-- 2st BOX END-->


<!-- 3st BOX-->
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="kutu">
      <h2>3rd TITLE</h2>

      <div class="items">
      </div>
      <h3>test</h3>
    </div>
    <a href="#">test</a>
</div>
<!-- 3st BOX END-->
```

I tried these methods, but I am not successful. I used nth-child and nth-of-type, but my desired result was not. How can I do that? Thank you

```
.kutu { 
      width: 600px;
      height: 300px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
.kutu:nth-of-type(2) h2{
      color: red;
    }
.kutu:nth-of-type(3) h2{
      color: green;
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you just add a class or ID(which ever one works best) to them? If you want to go the complicated route, with the given code you would target from `col-lg-6`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is the class is inside of the elements that are siblings

```css
.kutu { 
      width: 600px;
      height: 300px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
.kutu:nth-of-type(2) h2{
      color: red;
    }
.kutu:nth-of-type(3) h2{
      color: green;
    }
```

```html
<!-- 1st BOX-->
<div class="col-lg-6 kutu">
    <div class="">
      <h2>1st TITLE</h2>

      <div class="items">
      </div>
      <h3>test</h3>
    </div>
    <a href="#">test</a>
</div>
<!-- 1st BOX END-->


<!-- 2st BOX-->
<div class="col-lg-6 kutu">
    <div class="">
      <h2>2nd TITLE</h2>

      <div class="items">
      </div>
      <h3>test</h3>
    </div>
    <a href="#">test</a>
</div>
<!-- 2st BOX END-->


<!-- 3st BOX-->
<div class="col-lg-6 kutu">
    <div class="">
      <h2>3rd TITLE</h2>

      <div class="items">
      </div>
      <h3>test</h3>
    </div>
    <a href="#">test</a>
</div>
<!-- 3st BOX END-->
I tried these methods, but I am not successful. I used nth-child and nth-of-type, but my desired result was not. How can I do that? Thank you
```